# Visual Studio Code Compilation problem, c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, real-time-clock

There is an error when compiling the code in visual studio, the code and the error are copied here, the code seems to be fine still the problem is occurring, kindly help.The error keeps on coming, I've also attested a screenshot of the same,it might help in finding the mistake, do look into it as I am not able to interpret its meaning.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<windows.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
         int h,m,s,a,err; cout<<"Enter hour"<<endl;
             cin>>h;
         err=a=0;
         while (err==0)    {
            cout<<"Enter hour"<<endl;
            cin>>h;
            cout<<"Enter minutes"<<endl;
            cin>>m;
            cout<<"Enter seconds"<<endl;
            cin>>s;
    
            if(h<24&& m<60&& s<60)
            err++;
            else
            system("cls"); }
        while (a==0)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout<<h<<":"<<m<<":"<<s<<endl;
            Sleep(1000);
            s++;   
            { s=0;
              m++; }
            if (m>59)
            {m=0;
             h++;}
            if(h>24)
            {
                h=0;   }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

**THE ERROR**

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\acer\Desktop\C PROGRAMS\.vscode> dir


    Directory: C:\Users\acer\Desktop\C PROGRAMS\.vscode


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        12-05-2021     01:13                .vscode
-a----        11-05-2021     23:06             83 a.c
-a----        11-05-2021     23:45          54022 a.exe
-a----        12-05-2021     01:12            782 calc.clock.cpp
-a----        12-05-2021     02:18            723 calc.cpp
-a----        12-05-2021     01:32        3847555 calc.exe
-a----        12-05-2021     01:10            782 hello.cpp
-a----        11-05-2021     23:44          75943 hello.exe
-a----        11-05-2021     23:38             83 helloworld.c
-a----        06-04-2021     15:42            180 settings.json
   
PS C:\Users\acer\Desktop\C PROGRAMS\.vscode> .\calc.exe
    Program 'calc.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1 char:1
    + .\calc.exe
    + ~~~~~~~~~~.
    At line:1 char:1`enter code here`
    + .\calc.exe
    + ~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

[image]

Comment: how do you compile it?

Comment:  Please, easy on the ALL CAPS. It's considered YELLING and it's [ANNOYING](https://twitter.com/PHP_CEO).

Comment: Compiled goodly for me. More information required. Can you copy the full built output from VSC and paste it into the question

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 sir I've copied the output in the question, kindly look into it.

Comment: @tadman Yes Sir! Will keep that in mind. My apologies!

Comment: @user4581301 sir I've copied the output in the question as you suggested, kindly look into it.

Comment: There is no compilation command in there. You should show how you compile this program.

Comment: You have a file, but that file is not a valid executable. What we're looking for is something in the build instructions that says  "Export the raw object file, but call it an exe", "Cross-compile for Mac", "build a 16 bit application.", or the ever popular "Let's <expletive deleted> with this human meat-bag's head."

Comment: @user4581301 got it, sir! Actually, I was using cpp.exe build active file instead of g++.exe build active file. Thank you for your patient response. Appreciate it.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thank you for pointing that out sir, I got it. Appreciate your help.